# Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Could not get PipelineManager instance?

Tags: 2011, publishing

I'm trying to publish content & I'm getting the error shown below in the "deploying" phase. At first I was trying to publish to an MS SQL DB so I thought the problem was in my DB settings, but I switched to an all File system version of cd_storage_conf.xml & I am getting the same error.  Is "PipelineManager" a Tridion reference here?  If so, any clues on what the issue is?  I included a stack trace from the log file.  I noticed the " Unable to configure archive manager specific homes"  error, but I'm not sure what to make of that.

"Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Could not get PipelineManager instance, Could not get PipelineManager instance"

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not get PipelineManager instance
    at com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineManager.getInstance(PipelineManager.java:128) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.archiving.modules.DeploymentPipelineModule.process(DeploymentPipelineModule.java:90) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:74) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:67) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to configure archive manager specific homes, No Data Access Object for Archive, No Data Access Object for Archive
    at com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineManager.ensureDAOBundlePresent(PipelineManager.java:260) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineManager.configure(PipelineManager.java:170) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineManager.<init>(PipelineManager.java:155) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineManager.getInstance(PipelineManager.java:125) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
```

Comment: Could you share which version of Java you have installed on your deployment server?

Answer (score 2):

`PipelineManager` is part of Tridion's Archive Manager, the error `No Data Access Object for Archive` suggests that there is something wrong with your Archive Manager configuration in `cd_storage_conf.xml`.